# Rechange array so it could be sorted in C#

Tags: c#, arrays, sorting

I have been given this task to solve:

Write a program that reads an array of integers and removes from it a minimal number of elements in such a way that the remaining array is sorted in increasing order. Print the minimal number of elements that need to be removed in order for the array to become sorted.

Time limit 0.1sec.

Sample test:

Input:

1,
4,
3,
3,
6,
3,
2,
3

Output:

3

Unfortunately, my program is slower. This is my code:

```
using System;
static bool CheckAscending(List<int> list)
{
    bool ascending = true;

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        if (list[i] > list[i + 1])
        {
            ascending = false;
        }
    }

    return ascending;
}

static void Main()
{
    int n;
    n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    List<int> arr = new List<int>();
    List<int> sorted = new List<int>();
    int maxSubsetLenght = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
    }


    for (int i = 1; i <= (int)Math.Pow(2, n) - 1; i++)
    {
        int tempSubsetLenght = 0;
        List<int> temp = new List<int>();


        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            if (((i >> (j - 1)) & 1) == 1)
            {
                temp.Add(arr[j - 1]);
                tempSubsetLenght++;
            }

        }

        if ((tempSubsetLenght > maxSubsetLenght) && (CheckAscending(temp)))
        {
            sorted = temp;
            maxSubsetLenght = tempSubsetLenght;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(n - sorted.Count);
}
```

Can someone help me to make my program a bit faster. I will be glad if you could answer in the near future.

Comment: This like a assignment ?

Comment: Yes like a task. But I need to improve my program to be faster.

Comment: Well, I have tried but, I think it is impossible, because you need remove, check and also assign values from list to list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found how to soleve it and thanks @Gabor for your help :). Here is my solution:

```
using System;

static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        int currentNumber = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        numbers.Add(currentNumber);
    }
    int[] size = new int[numbers.Count];

    // Define each number as subsequence.
    for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        size[i] = 1;
    }

    int max = 1;
    // Compare current number with the numbers before.
    for (int i = 1; i < numbers.Count; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            if (numbers[i] >= numbers[j] && size[i] <= size[j] + 1)
            {
                size[i] = size[j] + 1;
                // Update max increasing subsequence.
                if (max < size[i])
                {
                    max = size[i];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Print numbers to remove as a result.
    int numbersToRemove = n - max;
    Console.WriteLine(numbersToRemove);
}
```

I think it would be helpful for other people, who have the same task to do like me.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE #2**

When there is a decrease then we should delete not only the current number but all the numbers before which are more than the new minValue.

The `Stopwatch` is in the `System.Diagnostic` namespace.

```
// int?[] numbers = new int?[] { 8, 1, 4, 3, 3, 6, 3, 2, 3 };
int?[] numbers = new int?[] { -7, -7, -7, -100, -100, -99, 4, -90, -80, -70 };

Console.WriteLine("Array: [{0}]", String.Join(", ", numbers));

System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch watch = new Stopwatch();
watch.Start();

int minValue = Int32.MinValue;

for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length - 1; i++)
{
    var currentNumber = numbers[i];
    var nextNumber = numbers[i + 1];

    if (currentNumber > nextNumber)
    {
        if (nextNumber < minValue)
        {
            numbers[i + 1] = null;
        }
        else
        {
            minValue = nextNumber.Value;

            for (int j = i; j >= 0; j--)
            {
                if (numbers[j] > minValue)
                {
                    numbers[j] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

watch.Stop();

Console.WriteLine("Result: {0}; Time: {1} ms", numbers.Count(number => number == null), watch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

Console.WriteLine("Array: [{0}]", String.Join(", ", numbers));
```

Comment: I know that is not a complete solution but it does reduce the execution time in every cycle. I don't know why someone downvoted it.

Comment: This doens't reduce the complexity of the problem. I can still be done in `O(n)` as @ Valentin said.

Comment: Well @Eser, I am not sure if you looked our discution with Valentin, but there are some examples in which your idea might not work properly.

Comment: I am not sure where is your mistake because, while checking unknown for me tests your program was incorrect. Fortunately, I restated my one and I will post it.

Comment: @KirilVasilev You may consider upvoting my answer if you found it useful. :) Could you please specify a test case (numbers) when my program was incorrect just to learn from that. Thanks.

Comment: Yes I was going to upvote your comment but I registered yesterday and I dont have enough reputation to vote. So here is an example, where your program does not work: int?[] numbers = new int?[] { -7, -7, -7, -100, -100, -99, 4, -90, -80, -70};

Comment: @Gabor could you tell me which "using System.  ; " do you use to have watch ☺

Comment: @KirilVasilev I updated my answer. I did not expect negative numbers and I think I found the mistake in the algorithm. Check it out. :)

Comment: Ok good job @Gabor! :) Now your program works properly! I will accept your answer :).